# Android .finish() works until app reboot

Tags: java, android

I have a slightly specific issue where I am able to successfully
finish() an activity while the app is currently running. Meaning that I can go from a Login page to the MainActivity and when the user presses back the app closes since the Login was finished, but when you open the app a second time it takes you to the Login page instead of MainActivity. Any clues as to why this is happening?

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        LoginActivity.this.finish();
```

Comment: Post your `AndroidManifest.xml` and your `LoginActivity.java`
But the issue is most probably that you don't check (and/or persist) whether the user has already logged-in so you can send him straight to `MainActivity`

Comment: you should make a check if the user has previously logged in  then  you should send him him mainactivity directly instead of login Activity,you can use shared preference for saving user credentials once the user logs in.Whenever he is coming back to login u will check if the user is saved in shared preference

Comment: Ok, I was under the impression that finish() would persist even after that app closes. So I'll just create a bool for if the user has already logged in and go straight to main if so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save some flag about login status probably in sharedpreferences and just check that flag for navigating to MainActivity on application launch

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your user to see a login prompt every time the app is opened you will need to cache the login token, preferably in SharedPreferences, and check for a valid token when the app starts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to check whether is user logged in or not

```
sharedpreferences pref = getsharedpreferences("user",MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedpreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

Now if user successfully logged in then add this value to sharedpreferences

```
editor.putBoolean("isLogin",true).apply();
```

And Now in launcher activity just check if it is false then open login activity intent or 
if true then MainActivity intent  by this code

```
if(pref.getBoolean("isLogin",false)){
   Intent i = new Intent(LauncherActivity,MainActivity.class);
   startActivity(i);
}
```